# How do you add an html comment to a jsoup comment

Tags: java, html, xml, jsoup

I'd like to add `<!-- message -->` into a jsoup document and I can't find an example. All I can find is

Comment

public Comment(String data,
               String baseUri)
Create a new comment node.
Parameters:
data - The contents of the comment
baseUri - base URI

with no usage example. And what should be the baseUri (how is it relevant?) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for adding comment to xml file:

```
root.addContent(new Comment("Info about " + cars[i][0]));
```

Comment: Thanks didn't quite work but pointed me in the right direction I ended up doing MyGraphml.select("graphml").before("<!-- strangerland[at]gmail.com -->");